# Are /me and redirects a good idea in API's?

Tags: php, api, http, laravel, http-status-codes

I am using Laravel to build my API which has awesome routing abilities.

I am wanting to support anywhere that a user ID could be passed in allowing passing "me" which means to represent the user the token represents.

E.g.

```
/users/1234                  => /users/me
/competitions?user=1234      => /competitions?user=me
/users/1234/threads/comments => /users/me/threads/comments
```

For the query string I will handle that internally replacing "me" with `Auth::user()->id` but for the routes where "me" is part of the path I am thinking of capturing those routes, replacing "me" with the output from `Auth::user()->id` and then doing a 3xx redirect to the modified route.

So two questions here.

1) Is this a feasible/good idea or should I just have a specific /users/currentUserInformation endpoint so the client can grab the current users id and then they are responsible for building the urls with the id returned from that response in?

2) What 3xx code fits the requirement? It's not a "You should request this information from here instead" it's simply a "The information you want is actually coming from here, but either are viable to get this information" (aka cache equal).

Answer (score 1):

1) If the client had to authenticate, then they should already know the current user. I'm not sure why you feel the need to track it and give it back to them, or provide a magic shortcut which looks it up. If you really want to do this, I'd suggest a separate resource for the currently authenticated user.

2) Looks like a 300 Multiple Choices is as close as you're going to get. Or possibly a 303 See Other. What you're describing sounds an awfully lot like having multiple canonical representations for a resource, which is considered non-RESTful.